# Solr - OpenNLP Patch 2899, Time taken by trainall.sh ? and failed test suite?

Tags: ant, solr, lucene, opennlp

I am following the instructions given at - https://wiki.apache.org/solr/OpenNLP

For English language testing: Until LUCENE-2899 is committed:

1. pull the latest trunk or 4.0 branch
2. apply the latest LUCENE-2899 patch
3. do 'ant compile'
4. cd solr/contrib/opennlp/src/test-files/training
5. run 'bin/trainall.sh'
       this will create binary files which will be included in the distribution when committed.
6. Now, go to trunk-dir/solr and run 'ant test-contrib'. It compiles the OpenNLP lucene and solr code against the OpenNLP libraries and uses the small model files.

I have followed the steps, at step5, I am not sure how much time it 'll take? as it have been running for 12+ hrs..

or I can execute step6 in parallel? I tried step 5 & 6 togather, then there is an error ; description mentioned below...

[junit4] Tests summary: 2 suites, 0 tests, 2 suite-level errors

BUILD FAILED
/home/svn2/solr/build.xml:201: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/home/svn2/solr/common-build.xml:417: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/home/svn2/solr/common-build.xml:449: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/home/svn2/lucene/common-build.xml:1250: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/home/svn2/lucene/common-build.xml:893: There were test failures: 2 suites, 0 tests, 2 suite-level errors

Please suggest. My high level objective is to index corpora sentence by sentence.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The script has `#!/usr/bin/env` at the top, which caused seemingly long runtime on my system as well (nothing is in fact running, as shown by the lack of generated test files).
Replacing that with `#!/bin/bash` promptly solved the problem (runtime a few seconds).